# Which WPF elements are "deliberate inheritance-blocking boundries"?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I'm trying to use a (Attached) DependencyProperty to communicate some state to a child element.
The official documentation[1] mentions "deliberate inheritance-blocking boundries" without explaining them.

Does anyone know which these are (beyond Frame)? How to identify them?

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/property-value-inheritance

Comment: Deliberately blocking controls aren't your only challenge.Is the child directly in your control?  Does it need to act on the inherited value or can the parent do so?

Comment: I got TabItems which contain UserControls. I'd like to implement reloads/refreshes of my data. Right now the Bindings in my child/UserControl to this AttachedProperty just don't work. No error, nothing. I double checked the documentation. I followed the implementation instruction to the point.
But this point in the documentation is super unclear to me.
I can post code tomorrow but right now I'm more interested in understanding this mechanism.

Comment: Bottom line is it's fragile and fiddly. If you handle the propertychanged callback in the parent then that will usually fire for all children and is a slightly more reliable option in my experience. I use that approach to drive re-building the NATO style unit icons in the GeneralStaff game. Just walking the tree is another. You might find the article I wrote about the subject interesting https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31705.wpf-inheriting-property-values-considered.aspx

Comment: The complication, of course, with tabitems is they will be switched out and only one is in the visual tree at a time to receive and notification of property change. I don't know but I guess that could be a problem. Remember that potentially absolutely everything which is below an element will inherit a dp marked as inherits. A tab sounds like it might have quite a lot in it - and there is overhead.